# Glowing box effect with shadow

Tags: css, border, glow

I have a problem with styling box. I need to create a glow effect with shadow at the bottom box. I'm stuck while creating this effect.

Glow effect what I need to create:

[image]

I tried to create this effect, but it looks very bad

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLPrZv)

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
}

.glow {
  width: 60%;
  height: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px yellow, 0 0 20px 10px #ffc600, 0px 0px 20px 0px yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="glow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show what you have tried, make a snippet.

Comment: I add link to codepen

Comment: master is here !! XD :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can approximate this using background coloration and some  filter

```css
.glow {
  height:40px;
  margin:50px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(190px 20px,white, gold 15%,transparent 30%),
    linear-gradient(to right,transparent, gold,transparent) center/100% 5px no-repeat;
  border-radius:100%;
  position:relative;
  filter:blur(1px);
}
.glow:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:inherit;
  filter:blur(7px);
}

body {
 background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="glow"></div>
```